# getting snapshot listener error in react application

Tags: reactjs, snapshot

I am new to react and I am building a todo application using react js and firebase. Firebase is successfully connected to react app but I am getting this error with [image: snapshot listener]. It is also saying FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions. Could you please explain what is the problem and How do I resolve it.

Here's the code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import db from './firebase';
import Todo from './Todo';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');


  useEffect(() => {

    db.collection('todos').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      setTodos(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data().todo));
    })
  }, []);


  const addTodo = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setTodos([...todos, input]);
    setInput('');
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form>
        <input placeholder="Your ToDo's" onChange={event => { setInput(event.target.value) }} value={input} />
        <Button type="submit" disabled={!input} variant="contained" onClick={addTodo} color="primary">
          Add todo
        </Button>
      </form>

      <ul>
        {todos.map(todo => (
          <Todo text={todo} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your `firestore.rules` to allow `read` on that collection/document.

Check this out: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

After you've updated the file, you can deploy your new rules with:

```
firebase deploy --only firestore:rules --project YOUR_PROJECT_ID
```